# Specifying default parameter in remote jenkins build with parameters using URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

For a remote jenkins URL that looks like

`curl -X POST 'MY_JENKINS_SERVER/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?token=12345&process_environment=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}'`

Is there a way I can specify the default value of the parameter in the URL itself? Along the lines of:
`curl -X POST 'MY_JENKINS_SERVER/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?token=12345&process_environment=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, default="local"}'`